# winforms to WPF Datagridview and datagrid

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am trying to get some code to work within WPF that i made in Winforms a while back. I am fairly new to WPF so im not sure how i can fix this.

The Winforms C# Code:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dvc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                dvc.ToolTipText = col.ColumnName;
                dvc.Name = col.ColumnName;
                dvc.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                dvc.DataPropertyName = col.ColumnName;
                dvc.Width = singleColWidth;
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dvc);
            }
```

The problem i have is that "BindingSource1" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: WPF is not WinForms.To populate a DataGrid in WPF, you set or bind its ItemsSource property to an IEnumerable like for example dt.DefaultView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem you're running into here is a complete difference in mindset between WPF and WinForms. Don't worry, everyone hits it!

The goal with WPF is to use a MVVM style of development. You can look more into what this means in general, but for your purposes this means you define your UI structure, your underlying data objects, and your UI class as seperate components.

You should define the columns for your datagrid in the XAML (or designer view), then attach your ItemSource to the grid (which is typically a collection of items). A good resource for learning about this is https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/.

I would step back from trying to translate an application you already have written and go step by step through a tutorial project with a site. You're going to need to unlearn a lot of habits from WinForms that are big problems in WPF-land.

Comment: @WilliamRobinson, I opened photos of the full code in Paint, but I cannot compile it. Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is not WinForms. To populate a `DataGrid` in WPF, you set or bind its `ItemsSource` property to an `IEnumerable` like for example `dt.DefaultView`.

A simple text column is represented by the `DataGridTextColumn` class so the equivalent code in WPF would look something like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    DataGridTextColumn dvc = new DataGridTextColumn();
    dvc.Name = col.ColumnName;
    dvc.Header = col.ColumnName;
    dvc.Binding = new Binding(col.ColumnName);
    dvc.Width = singleColWidth;
    DataGrid1.Columns.Add(dvc);
}
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Having that said, there are probably better ways of doing what you are trying to do. If you are serious about learning WPF, you should really learn the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern. It is *the* recommended pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesnt like being changed from Datagridviewtextboxcolumn to DataGridTextColumn. Complains there is no definition for name, header, binding, width and such.

Comment: @Zevulos: What if you use the fully qualified name (`System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn`)? If this doesn't work, it seems like you are not in the context of a WPF application after all...